# How remove middle of lines from ps?

Tags: linux, grep, cut, ps

I'm trying to make the output of a `ps -ef` more readable on Red Hat Linux. I know this has been asked many times, but I've several java processes that I regulary need to monitor and the line length for each process is atleast 500 characters but each line is a different length. I need the 1st 14 characters so I get the pid and around the last 40 characters of the same line to get the name.

What I've got so far is:

```
ps -ef | grep -v 'eclipse' | grep java | cut -c1-14
```

which strips out my copies of Eclipse that are running and then gets the other java processes and then cuts in the 1st part of the line.

I know how to get the last part by using `rev` both sides of the cut, but I can't work out how to combine the 2 together.

Comment: if you're just after java processes why not use jps (is part of stantdard VM distribution from oracle) ?

Comment: Look at `ps -o format` to get exactly the fields you want.

Comment: Could you post a sample of your desired output?

Comment: @BigMike - Thanks for that - another good alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give `cut` several regions to cut but it can't cut from the end, so to cut the last 40 characters, you need to know the line length in advance.

I suggest to use a more powerful tool like `gawk`:

```
ps -ef|gawk '
/eclipse/ {next}
/java/ {
    printf("%-10s %8s ...%s\n", $1, $2, substr($0,length()-40));
}'
```

which also allows you to format the output nicely.